# C++ Read and append

Tags: c++, append

Hello everyone I need help with one of the excercise I am doing. I have searched alot but didn't found what I was looking.
So, I want my program to read from one .txt file and then gives output in another .txt file.

```
Source File have this contents.
Name Salary 
Aamir 12000 
Amara 15000
Adnan 13000
Afzal 11500

Output File should have this 
Name Salary 
Aamir 14000
Amara 17000
Adnan 15000
Afzal 13500
```

The program should read the source file and add 2000 to the salary in the output file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char c;
    char inputFile[] = "my-file.txt";
    char outputFile[] = "my-file-out.txt";

    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;

    inFile.open(inputFile, ios::in);

    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout << "The file cannnot be open please check" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    outFile.open(outputFile, ios::out | ios::ate);

    while ((c = inFile.get()) != EOF)
    {

        outFile.put(c);
    }

    inFile.close();
    outFile.close();
}
```

I was able to copy the content from source file to output file after some struggle but now no matter what I do it won't give me the desirable solution. What should I add into the code that would give the correct output.

Comment: You seem to be going about this task in a very odd way with get and put. Why don't you read the file line by line into a `std::string` using getline() and process the string for each line then write the line back to the new file.

Comment: You should read the text file by line and for each line tokenize by the sepatator ' ' (blank character). For the line "Aamir 12000" you will get two tokens: token[0] = "Aamir" and token[1] = "12000". Then you need to convert token[1] to an integer (?) value, do the math and generate the new line string from token[0] and the integer value, where you added 2000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. prefer using `const std::string` over `const char*`
2. extract the first line and write to output stream. `std::getline` can help you.
3. read data from source with `operator>>` if your source data constists of fixed types of datas.
4. raise salary and write to dest file with `operator<<`

Following code works but I omitted handling exceptions or erros for simplicity. You should add handling code when opening, reading, writing data and closing streams.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string;

int main() {
  const string name_input_file = "D:/my-file.txt";
  std::ifstream ifs(name_input_file);

  const string name_output_file = "D:/my-file-out.txt";
  std::ofstream ofs(name_output_file);

  string fist_line;
  std::getline(ifs, fist_line);
  ofs << fist_line << '\n';

  string name;
  int salary;
  while (ifs && ofs) {
    ifs >> name >> salary;
    salary += 2'000;
    ofs << name << ' ' << salary << '\n';
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a dirty solution. Reads my-file.text, adds 2000 to each salaries and writes the new strings to my-file-out.txt. Note that my-file-out.txt will lose its previous data everytime you run the program.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::ifstream ifile;
  std::ofstream ofile;
  ifile.open("my-file.txt", std::ifstream::in);
  ofile.open("my-file-out.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc);
  std::string line{};
  bool flag{true};

  while (std::getline(ifile, line))
  {
    if (flag){ flag = false; ofile << line << "\n"; continue; }
    std::string salary{};
    for (size_t i{line.length() - 1}; i >= 0; --i)
    {
      if (line[i] == ' ') break;
      salary += line[i];
    }
    std::reverse(salary.begin(), salary.end());
    line.replace(line.length() - salary.length(), line.length(), std::to_string(std::stoi(salary) + 2000));
    ofile << line << "\n";
  }

  ifile.close();
  ofile.close();
}
```